# Which SQL command can I use to see the structure of a table on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, structure

I have a table on a SQL Server and I would like to export its structure to send to a colleague. Which SQL command should I issue to get the structure? I don't have access to the SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
sp_help '<TableName>'
```

will give you the structure of a table

Also you can use the information_Schema to get a detailed information,

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Brad Schulz has a pretty awesome DDL generating script he just blogged about the other day:
(there are a few limitations with it though)

http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/06/more-fun-with-hyperlinks-ddl-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has tools for designing and browsing database schema under Data Connections in Server Explorer. Certain versions also have full schema and data comparison tools similiar to [Red Gate's Sql Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_compare/index.htm)