# Describe table structure

Tags: sql, database

Which query will give the table structure with column definitions in SQL?

Comment: You should specify your database vendor as the command(s) differ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which SQL command can I use to see the structure of a table on SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159236/which-sql-command-can-i-use-to-see-the-structure-of-a-table-on-sql-server)

Comment: It's not a duplicate since there the database is specified.

Comment: @schmijos: actually it's implied, at best. "sql" does NOT mean "MS Sql Server" and it's irritating that so many people seem to think it's acceptable to use the generic term to specify a specific vendor. "sql" means Structured Query Language and Microsoft is not the only "sql".

Comment: @bane I actually thought the same and tried to answer the generic "SQL" question. But the OP deleted my answer. That's was reason for the implication. And in the meantime the question was edited from MSSQL to SQL. So I don't get it anymore.

Comment: @schmijos +1 -- I guess a case of when history-rewriting is a bad thing. :\

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx) tablename in sql server -- `sp_help [ [ @objname = ] 'name' ]`

[desc](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tools/rtoolsijcomrefdescribe.html) tablename in oracle -- `DESCRIBE { table-Name | view-Name }`

Answer (score 79):

It depends from the database you use. Here is an incomplete list:

- sqlite3: `.schema table_name`
- Postgres (psql): `\d table_name`
- SQL Server: [`sp_help table_name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx) (or `sp_columns table_name` for only columns)
- Oracle DB2: [`desc table_name`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0002019.htm) or `describe table_name`
- MySQL: `describe table_name` (or `show columns from table_name` for only columns)

Answer (score 28):

In MySQL you can use `DESCRIBE <table_name>`

Answer (score 23):

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='<Table Name>'
```

You can get details like column datatype and size by this query

Comment: Note that this command runs extremely slow in case you have many tables. In my company we have >5k tables, each table has 10,20, some has 100 cols, and it results it read timeout operation. `describe` is prefered

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'student'
```

Answer (score 8):

```
DESCRIBE tableName
```

Check [MySQL describe command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html)

Answer (score 5):

For Sybase aka SQL Anywhere the following command outputs the structure of a table:

```
DESCRIBE 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server use exec sp_help

```
USE db_name;
exec sp_help 'dbo.table_name'
```

For MySQL, use describe

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Highlight table name in the console and press <kbd>ALT+F1</kbd>

Comment: OP asked for the query not for a vague steps in a unspecified console.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL, use the Keyword 'sp_help'
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your database vendor. Mostly it's the "information schema" you should Google for (applies to MySQL, MSSQL and perhaps others).

Answer (score 1):

Sql server

```
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(100)
SET @tableName = N'members' -- change with table name
SELECT
    [column].*,
    COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id([column].[TABLE_NAME]), [column].[COLUMN_NAME], 'IsIdentity') AS [identity]
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS [column] 
WHERE
    [column].[Table_Name] = @tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

In DBTools for Sybase, it's `sp_columns your_table_name`.