# T-SQL - Insert Statement Ignoring a Column

Tags: t-sql, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a dozen or so columns. I only know the name of the first column and the last 4 columns (in theory, I could only know the name of one column and not its position)

How can I can I write a statement which ignores this column? At the moment I do various column counts in ASP and construct a statement that way but was wondering if there was an easier way

**UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO tblName VALUES ("Value for col2", "Value for col3")
```

but the table has a col4 and potentially more, which I'd be ignoring.

I basically have a CSV file. This CSV file has no headers. It has 'X' less columns than the table I'm inserting into. I would like to insert the data from the CSV into the table.

There are many tables of different structures and many CSV files. I have created a ASP page to take any CSV and upload it to the corresponding table (based on a parameter within the CSV file).

It works fine, I was just wondering that when I was doing the `INSERT` statement, if I could ignore certain columns and cut down on my code.

So let's say the CSV has data as follows

```
123 | 456 | 789
234 | 567 | 873
```

The table has a structure of

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5
```

I currently construct an insert statement that says

```
INSERT into tblName ("123", "456","789","","")
```

However I was wondering if there was a way I could omit the empty values by somehow "ignoring" the columns. As mentioned, the column names are not known apart from the ones I have no data for.

Comment: Ignores *which* column? From your initial paragraph, I was thinking that you'd want to ignore the columns you don't know of, but the only thing I can make "this column" match with is the first column (which you say you do know about). Can you edit your question and add a concrete example of such a table, the information you have, and the `INSERT` statement that you're wanting to generate?

Comment: (Alternative thinking - you've found a very roundabout way of saying that you want to duplicate some rows in an arbitrary table with an `IDENTITY` column (with the system to define new `IDENTITY` values for these new rows)).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ignores any column I want to ignore. Updated.

Comment: How does that insert work?  The stated table structure is 6 columns.

Comment: The ID is a primary auto increment field so that's taken care of

Comment: I thought you always had to specify the column names to insert into a table with an auto increment.   I think it used to be that way.

Comment: I don't have to since it auto increments

Answer (score 1):

There is no Sql shortcut for

```
Select * (except column col1) from ...
```

You have to construct your Sql from database metadata, like you already did if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the columns that you want to insert.

So instead of...

```
INSERT INTO tblName VALUES ("Value for col2", "Value for col3")
```

You could specify column names...

```
INSERT INTO tblName (ColumnName1, ColumnName2) VALUES ("Value for col2", "Value for col3")
```

Comment: I have no idea what the column names are though

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, thought you only wanted to insert to the column names you knew. How about first retrieving the table structure or is that what you are already doing (eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159236/which-sql-command-can-i-use-to-see-the-structure-of-a-table-on-sql-server)?