# Load my combobox with the column names of my database table

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using the following method to load data from a database and fill into my combo box. For example if my database table is as follows:

Table Name: PERSONS

```
Person_Id Person_Name
1         Jason
2         Carl
```

The names Jason and Carl will be loaded into the combo box. This works fine. I am now looking to load my combo box only with the column names as in Person_ID, Person_Name. Is there a way I could modify my current method to do that? Please advice.

```
private void fillCombo(string query, string name, ComboBox c)
{
    MySqlCommand cmdReader;
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        cmdReader = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        myReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string temp;
            if (name != null)
            {
                temp = myReader.GetString(name);
                if (!c.Items.Contains(temp))
                {
                    c.Items.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        myReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Unable to load data from database"); }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fillCombo("SELECT * FROM PERSONS;", "Person_Name", comboBox1);  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159236/which-sql-command-can-i-use-to-see-the-structure-of-a-table-on-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get column names like this:

```
cmdReader = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
myReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader();

for(int index=0; index < reader.FieldCount; index++)
{
   c.Items.Add(myReader.GetName(index));
}
```

Comment: Yes it was. Just typo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GetSchemaTable() method on the MySqlDataReader:

```
private void fillCombo(string query, string name, ComboBox c)
{
    MySqlCommand cmdReader;
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        cmdReader = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        myReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader();

        var table = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

        foreach (DataColumn column in Table.Columns)
        {
            string s = column.ColumnName;

            if (!c.Items.Contains(s))
            {
                c.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }

        myReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Unable to load data from database"); }
}
```